# Attempt to call a method but I get a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I want to create a connection through socket but I'm having trouble with the graphic of my App:

**This is my activity:**

```
public class Messaggi2 extends ActionBarActivity{

LinearLayout mLayout;
ScrollView scroll;
EditText scriviMessaggi;
Button invia; 
Socket connessione;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messaggi2);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearScrollLayout);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2);
    scriviMessaggi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Scrivi);
    invia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Invia);

    LavoraDietro asd = new LavoraDietro(connessione);
       asd.execute(); 
}


private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_broadcast_incoming_pressed);
    return textView;
}


private TextView createNewTextViewSent(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams llparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llparams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    final TextView textViewSent = new TextView(this);
    textViewSent.setLayoutParams(llparams);
    textViewSent.setText(text);
    textViewSent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_outgoing_normal);
    return textViewSent;
}

public void AggiungiTextALlayout(String messaggio){
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(messaggio));  
    aggiornaScroll();
}
public void AggiungiTextInviatoALlayout(String messaggio){
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextViewSent(messaggio));  
    aggiornaScroll();
}

public void aggiornaScroll(){ 
    scroll.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() { 
             scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
           }
        });
}
}
```

**This is my AsynTask class:**

```
public class LavoraDietro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Socket> {
Socket connessione;
boolean vediSeDeviPartire; 
Messaggi2 mess = new Messaggi2();

public LavoraDietro(Socket connessione){
    this.connessione = connessione;
}

@Override  
protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params){ 
    try {
        InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.71");
        connessione = new Socket(local , 7000); 

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return null;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    return connessione;
} 

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Socket result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result != null){ 
    vediSeDeviPartire = true;
    mess.AggiungiTextALlayout("Sono connesso al server");
    mess.AggiungiTextALlayout("I canali sono aperi..");
    }
    else{ 
    mess.AggiungiTextALlayout("ERRORE CONNESSIONE AL SERVER ");
    }
    }
}
```

Using this code when I start my app the connection is established and then it crashes. What I see on my Logcat is this Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So I tried to delete the content of my `onPostExecute` and everything works perfect. So the mistake is to try to call the method `AggiungiTextAlLayout` on my `AsyncTask` class.
Can someone help me with this? Can someone suggest me something? I'm new in this field so I know that this is a stupid thing but I need help.

Thanks guys in advance

**EDITED WITH THE SOLUTION**

Thanks to Ataulm I got the problem and I solved it I changed the costructor of my LavoraDietro class (unfortunatly I can't change the name of variables and classes in English. But next time I ll use english Name of course )

**LavoraDietro Class**

```
public class LavoraDietro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Socket> {
Socket connessione;
boolean vediSeDeviPartire; 
Messaggi2 action;

public LavoraDietro(Socket connessione, Messaggi2 action){
    this.connessione = connessione;
    this.action = action;
}


@Override  
protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params){ 
    try {
        InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.71");
        connessione = new Socket(local , 7000); 

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return null;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    return connessione;
} 

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Socket result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result != null){ 
    vediSeDeviPartire = true;
    action.AggiungiTextALlayout("Sono connesso al server");
    action.AggiungiTextALlayout("I canali sono aperi..");
}
    else{ 
    action.AggiungiTextALlayout("ERRORE CONNESSIONE AL SERVER ");

    }
    }
}
```

**And in the Messaggi2 class I changed the call of the constructor in this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messaggi2);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearScrollLayout);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2);
    scriviMessaggi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Scrivi);
    invia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Invia);


    LavoraDietro asd = new LavoraDietro(connessione, this);
       asd.execute();
```

Comment: Create `Context` as the second parameter of `AsyncTask's` constructor and pass activity's context to it. Use the Context in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @Onik use the `Context` to do what?

Comment: @ataulm 1) In onCreate(): LavoraDietro asd = new LavoraDietro(connessione, this); 2) public LavoraDietro(Socket connessione, Context context){
    this.connessione = connessione; this.context = context;
} 3) Use this.context in onPostExecute casting to `Messaggi2` class. In this case it won't be null.

Comment: @Onik there doesn't seem to be any benefit of passing Context, if you have to cast it to the Messaggi2 class in the only place you're going to use it

Comment: @ataulm What would you suggest?

Comment: @Onik probably more transparent to have `Messaggi2` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AsyncTask has a reference to `mess` which is an object of type `Messaggi2`.

`Messaggi2` is a subclass of `Activity`. You attempt, inside your AsyncTask, to create a new instance of that class.

The Android system has no awareness of this object; it has called none of the life cycle methods, such as `onCreate()` where the activity's layout would typically be inflated. This means that none of your views are inflated nor even initialised.

When you call `mess.AggiungiTextALlayout("Sono connesso al server");`, `mLayout` is null.

The NPE you see may likely not even be this one.

**TL;DR: don't instantiate your `Activity` objects like Java objects; use them as specified within the Android framework.**

I suspect you have this Activity starting correctly somewhere. The mistake is that you've not associated that activity with your Asynctask. When you create `LavoraDietro`, you pass a reference to the `Socket` in the constructor; you can also pass a reference to your activity, and assign that to the `mess` field, instead of calling `new Messaggi2()`. I'm not advocating this structure. But that is the issue at hand.

A few general tips to help you avoid this in future / or spot it faster:

- be consistent with your naming; it's difficult to read your code when you're switching between English and Italian.
- it's equally difficult for others to read your code if you don't maintain follow Java conventions with class/method names.
- When you're extending `Activity`, it's typical to append the word "Activity" after your class; in this example `new Messaggi2Activity()` would have been easier to spot.
- Where you're able, pass a Class's dependencies as parameters in the constructor; don't rely on constructing these dependencies yourself inside that class. Once you do this, you can begin to draw lines around what your class is responsible for; the less it's responsible for, the harder it is for your class to mess up.

Comment: OH.. now i get it. But How can I solve this problem. Have you got some advice?

Comment: yes I added _a_ "solution" as an edit to this answer

Comment: thanks a lot. I try to code something using your advice and i edit my Post with the complete solution. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, be sure not to obscure your original question when you edit your post and make it clear that you're editing it with the complete solution, so as not to confuse people who come later.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is for put a variable with no "data", verify your variables

Comment: @Briesanji user3700966 is correct; see my answer below